# Is there any way to send this Keyboard.Press(); command wireless to my PC via Bluetooth?

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth

I have already been able to implement the wireless data sending of my Arduino Micro board via Bluetooth. I used following code to send my sensor data from the arduino board to PC. But I want it to be able to do a Keyboard.Press(); according to the data I receive from my sensors attached to the Micro board.

Is there any way to send this Keyboard.Press();  command wireless to my PC via Bluetooth ?

I use Arduino Micro with HC-05 to send data to the PC wireless.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "Wire.h"
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU9250.h"

MPU9250 accelgyro;
I2Cdev   I2C_M;

int16_t ax, ay, az;
int16_t gx, gy, gz;
int16_t mx, my, mz;
float Axyz[3];

const int rxPort = 8; // connected to Bluetooth TX
const int txPort = 9; // connected to Bluetooth RX
SoftwareSerial myConnection = SoftwareSerial(rxPort, txPort);

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Initializing I2C devices...");
  accelgyro.initialize();
  Serial.println("Testing device connections...");
  Serial.println(accelgyro.testConnection() ? "MPU9250 connection successful" : "MPU9250 connection failed");
  delay(1000);
  myConnection.begin(9600);

}

void loop() 
{
  myConnection.print(mapX);
  myConnection.print("  ,  ");
  myConnection.println(mapY);
  ////Keyboard.press('a');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For bluetooth v2 you need a HID-enabled bluetooth module. Once I knew this product

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10938

but now they retired it.

If you want to move to bluetooth v4 I don't know. Searching on the web it appears that you will need to implement "HID over GATT profile" (HOGP).

I found [this library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/ble-sdk-arduino) for some ble chips (nRF8001, nRF2740/nRF2741) which has examples of a keyboard over bluetooth; otherwise if you already have a BT4 board try looking for libraries which implement that profile, or try porting it to your platform.

Of course this only applies to bluetooth 4 boards, since bluetooth 2 has some fixed "classes" (so you can't turn a BT-serial adapter into a BT-HID device).